# В данном предложениии "Не ограничены" или "Неограниченны". Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Минимальный и максимальный сроки не ограничены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос № 300901
Как правильно: "Срок годности неограничен/не ограничен"? Это краткое прилагательное или причастие? Даже у вас на сайте ранее было два разных ответа. Так как же все таки?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Предпочтительно: *срок годности **не ограничен***.

Считаю так же. Обычно, чем ближе к концу предложения, тем уместнее раздельное написание и произношение.

Если они не ограничены, то как бы и нет минимального и максимального срока — оригинальная фраза звучит сомнительно. Тогда лучше сказать просто: *сроки не ограничены*.